# How do I enable smooth animation during dynamic addition of components in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

In my React Native app I have a card which has a conditional `<Text>` component which is rendered on press of a button and removed on triggering the same button.

This is what it my code looks like:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.card}>
      <Button onPress={() => this.setState({ triggered: !this.state.triggered })} title="Click to Expand" />
      <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</Text>
      {this.state.triggered && <Text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</Text>}
    </View>
  </View>
```

And the CSS for it:

```
container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  card: {
    width: "90%",
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderRadius: 15,
    alignSelf: "center",
    padding: "5%"
  },
```

My full code available on an online emulator provided here: (https://snack.expo.io/@eddyj/thrilled-pudding)

So far so good, everything works as expected, however the transitions itself is not smooth at all. It just appears/disappears. How can I animate the card so it  gradually increases and decreases its height? Is that possible?

Comment: as per help pages: please post code writhing the questing.Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS

Comment: @SherylHohman Thank you for the useful links. I have now added Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to this post. The full live example is not available on sqlfiddle.com but on snack.expo since it is easier for React Native projects => https://snack.expo.io/@eddyj/thrilled-pudding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these services for smooth rendering from react-native [Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#layoutanimation-api)

```
import {
  NativeModules,
  LayoutAnimation 
} from 'react-native';

const { UIManager } = NativeModules;

componentWillUpdate() {
   UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true)
   LayoutAnimation.spring();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this a few ways, but you'll likely want to make use of the Animated library:

`import { Animated } from 'react-native'`

You store the (style property) value in state:

`this.state = { myViewHeight: new Animated.Value(300) }`

(`myViewHeight` would be used as a style prop in this example, `<View style={{ height: myViewHeight }}`)

And then to alter the value gradually, run an animation on it:

```
Animated.timing(this.state.myViewHeight, {
  toValue: 600,
  duration: 300
}).start()
```

In this example, it would gradually raise the height of the view from 300 to 600.

However, since you want to show more text, I think if I were you I might convert the text to an array of words and animate the percent of words shown.

There's a good guide [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#animated-api).

Comment: I think this would work great but I do not wish to have a fixed value for `height` (`300` nor `600`). How can I implement the same logic without knowing the exact height and without setting a fixed one?

Comment: You can store the words in an array and animate the number of words shown with array.slice(0, n) where n is the animated value. It's really up to you, but knowing how to use Animated might help you out.